# Problem with json when I unmarshal [] bytes into struct after converting "Id" is not correct

Tags: go

I have a problem with json when I unmarshal [] bytes into struct after converting "Id" is not correct

Id:  1606146401088049402 => 1606146401088049400

```css
`{"status":200,"success":true,"data":{"id":1606146401088049402,"created_at":"2020-11-23T22:46:41.092+07:00","updated_at":"2020-11-23T22:46:41.092+07:00","role":[{"code":"admin","name":"admin"}],"userName":"","phone":"0385666301","email":"congnguyen008@gmail.com","name":"","gender":"","title":"","firstName":"Nguyên","lastName":"Nguyễn","fullName":"Nguyên Nguyễn","displayName":"Nguyên Nguyễn","company":"","department":"","photo":"0385666301","addresses":"","phoneNumber":"","active":true,"lastTimeLogin":"2020-12-23T09:27:30.72+07:00","logged":{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MDg2OTQwNTAsImlkIjoiMTYwNjE0NjQwMTA4ODA0OTQwMiIsIm5hbWUiOiJOZ3V5w6puIE5ndXnhu4VuIiwicm9sZSI6W3siY29kZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIn1dfQ.Spj_wWPxRrs2tYYhCmNCWaZVWVack74k9ab1FpeQsf8","time_login":"2020-12-23 09:27:30.720385 +0700 +07 m=+56.589410521","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MDkyOTUyNTAsImlkIjoiMTYwNjE0NjQwMTA4ODA0OTQwMiIsIm5hbWUiOiJOZ3V5w6puIE5ndXnhu4VuIiwicm9sZSI6W3siY29kZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIn1dfQ.mO08BTq9SUns7OPCOrDeUbZojYkw3tjUaMeIQ_e2e2U"}}}`
```

Code

https://play.golang.org/p/MKmkLGPfwFa

```html
func main() {
    jsonData := `{"status":200,"success":true,"data":{"id":1606146401088049402}}`
    response := Response{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &response)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    user := User{}

    userJson, _ := json.Marshal(response.Data)

    json.Unmarshal(userJson, &user)

    fmt.Println(user.Id)
    fmt.Printf("%T", user.Id)
}

type User struct {
    Id       int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primarykey"`
    UserName string `json:"userName"`
}

type Response struct {
    Status  int         `json:"status"`
    Success bool        `json:"success"`
    Data    interface{} `json:"data,omitempty"`
    Message string      `json:"message,omitempty"`
    Input   interface{} `json:"input,omitempty"`
    Error   error       `json:"error,omitempty"`
    Paging  interface{} `json:"paging,omitempty"`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to postpone json processing.. Instead of using interface, marshal and then unmarshal, you could use `json.RawMessage`, like this:

https://play.golang.org/p/LR1OXWpk_sF

This eliminates a `Marshal` operation and wrong type convertion problems.

Answer (score 0):

To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
float64, for JSON numbers

float64 type produces the faulty unmarshalling.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

```
type Response struct {
    Status  int         `json:"status"`
    Success bool        `json:"success"`
    Data    Datam       `json:"data,omitempty"`
    Message string      `json:"message,omitempty"`
    Input   interface{} `json:"input,omitempty"`
    Error   error       `json:"error,omitempty"`
    Paging  interface{} `json:"paging,omitempty"`
}
type Datam struct{
    Id int64 `json:"id"`
}
```

correctly unmarshals given id.